wcpdf_download_pdf shortcode doesn't work on manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_custom_column
The code:
echo do_shortcode('[wcpdf_download_pdf document_type="invoice" link_text="print" order_id="5746"]');

works on front end but it doesn't work on 'manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_custom_column' action hook, in this hook other shortcodes work just fine. My problem is that it also doesn't throw an error. How can I force a shortcode to run correctly?
add_action('manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_custom_column', 'factor_rows', 10, 2);
function factor_rows($column, $order)
{
    if ('print' == $column) {
        echo do_shortcode('[wcpdf_download_pdf order_id="5746"]');
    }
}

I tried other shortcodes and they worked fine and I also tried it elsewhere and it also worked fine it's just the shortcode doesn't work on that action hook. Error logging the shortcode returns empty string.

Can you try with echo do_shortcode('[wcpdf_download_pdf document_type="invoice" link_text="print" order_id="5746"]'); inside factor_rows too?

I tried, didn't work. I also tried other shortcodes and they worked, it added the data to every columns.
